# How to handle situation in Android when there are more than one app exists in any device to perform some action for any incoming SMS?

Tags: android, sms, handler

What will happen when in an handset there are some apps which have defined some action on **onReceive()** method for any incoming SMS and any one app is calling **abortBroadcast()** method to remove sms from Inbox. Of course, I don't know that what priority they have defined in their App for their listener. 
                  So in such scenario suppose I also want to perform some action on any incoming sms and also want to keep it in user's Inbox folder then how I will get that SMS when some other app have already read it and removed it too.

Answer (score 0):

Since sms is a protected broadcast and only Android framework can send the broadcast, no one can do a `abortBroadcast` on it.
For storing of sms you should never use the Default sms `contentProvider`, since that will be updated by system Messaging application. You should use your own db or just fetch the items from the db already stored by default messaging application.

Comment: Thx for ur reply. But I am able to do abortBroadcast(). Point is if someone else is doing the same thing then how my app will be able to perform some action on the same incoming sms which has been deleted by another app.